# Using custom configuration provider for Serilog

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, serilog, audit-logging

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API application in which I am using `Serilog` with `Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer` sink.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to read Serilog's MSSQL sink configuration (E.g. connection string) using some custom configuration provider if it's not possible to configure settings in the appsettings file?
2. Is it possible to do some settings on `LoggerConfiguration` at the end AFTER all the required dependencies are registered? (Something like what we do using `IPostConfigureOptions`.)

**High level description of the problem if you want to know what I am up to:**

In my organization, all application settings are stored in a common database. What it means is that the ConnectionString I need for the Serilog  MSSqlServer sink will also be in the common database.

Serilog is configured at the `Host` level using `IHostBuilder` in `Program.cs`. On the other hand, the services which read settings from our common database are registered in ASP.NET Core's DI in `Startup.cs`.

I added a class named `SerilogPostConfigure` which implements `IPostConfigureOptions<LoggerConfiguration>` and registered it in `Startup.cs` like this `services.ConfigureOptions<SerilogPostConfigure>()`. In this class, I inject all the dependencies which can help me connect to the common database to get the required connection string. However, this class is never invoked ! I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use a custom configuration provider on ASP.NET Core level. You can tell the ASP.NET Core app to read the application's configuration from custom places (It reads from your appsettings.json file and environment variables by default).

Here is an article about creating a custom config provider, that reads configuration from a database: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-configuration-provider